# can't create pods - failed calling webhook "sidecar-injector.istio.io"

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, istio

Kubernetes version: 1.17.14-gke.400

I am having trouble creating pods with istio setup, I am getting a timeout error from the sidecar injector.

I setup istio (1.8.1) with this command:

```
istioctl install --set profile=minimal \
 --set values.cni.cniBinDir=/home/kubernetes/bin \
 --set 'values.cni.excludeNamespaces[0]'=kube-system \
 --set 'values.cni.excludeNamespaces[1]'=istio-system \
 --set 'values.cni.excludeNamespaces[2]'=backend \
 --set components.cni.enabled=true \
 --set components.cni.namespace=kube-system
```

Then when I try to deploy the sleep sample I get one of these two errors
`kubectl apply -f samples/sleep/sleep.yaml`

```
Error creating: Internal error occurred: failed calling webhook "sidecar-injector.istio.io": Post https://istiod.istio-system.svc:443/inject?timeout=30s: context deadline exceeded
```

or

```
Error creating: Internal error occurred: failed calling webhook "sidecar-injector.istio.io": Post https://istiod.istio-system.svc:443/inject?timeout=30s: net/http: request canceled while waiting for connection (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers)
```

I do have network policies enabled, but I don't have any setup in kube-system of istio-system. Also, when I curl that endpoint I get a 400 error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My issue turned out to be that I needed to update the firewall rule to add port 15017 even though I do not have a private cluster: https://istio.io/latest/docs/setup/platform-setup/gke/

Answer (score 1):

There is a known issue with the upgrade from GKE 1.16 to 1.17. Any custom resources you created in the istio-system namespace are deleted during an upgrade to 1.17. These resources must be manually recreated. We recommend not upgrading clusters with the Istio add-on to 1.17 until the fix is rolled out. The issue only occurs during upgrades, so new clusters are not affected. Check this [release notes](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/release-notes#known-20201006) for more details.

Comment: this is a brand new installation of istio

Comment: I am on bare metal cluster & encounter this error, there is no firewall settings. message: >-
        Internal error occurred: failed calling webhook
        "namespace.sidecar-injector.istio.io": failed to call webhook: Post
        "https://istiod.istio-system.svc:443/inject?timeout=10s": context
        deadline exceeded
      reason: FailedCreate